# Return Type Nill

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
 func getAddressFromLatLon() {



    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    var currentLocation = CLLocation()

    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorized){

        currentLocation = locManager.location!

    }




    var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let lat: Double = Double(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    //21.228124
    let lon: Double = Double(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    //72.833770
    let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    center.latitude = lat
    center.longitude = lon

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    var placemark: AnyObject
    var error: NSError
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locManager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if (placemark?.count)! > 0 {
            let pm = (placemark?[0])! as CLPlacemark
            //self.addressString = pm.locality! + pm.country!
            let adress = pm.locality! + " " + pm.country!

            print(adress)
        } else {
            print("Error with data")
        }
    })



}
```

Sorry about this very basic question. I am fairly new to swift and I am trying to reverse geocode a latitude and longitude. I am trying to return the adress from the reverse geocoding, but it seems to be returning nil. The function in question is getAddressFromLatLon() and I have tried adding a return type but it is returning nil. When I print in the function itself, the correct value is printed but for some reason  I am having difficulty getting the adress to return so I can pass it to other classes/functions.

Comment: func getAddressFromLatLon() is a void function. You cannot expect it to return any value.

Comment: One more thing i want to confirm, Is print(adress) displaying the desired result?..

Comment: did you got lat long  in this function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold the value which you get from reserver geocoder and just need to use it.

```
  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locManager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if (placemark?.count)! > 0 {
                let pm = (placemark?[0])! as CLPlacemark
                //self.addressString = pm.locality! + pm.country!
                let adress = pm.locality! + " " + pm.country!

                // Store value into global object and you can use it...
               // Another option, you can call one function and do necessary steps in it
                mainLocality = pm.locality
                mainCountry - pm.country       
                updateGeoLocation() // Call funcation

                print(adress)
 } else {
            print("Error with data")
        }
    })


func updateGeoLocation(){
     // You can use both object at here
     //    mainLocality
     //    mainCountry
     // Do your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initilise CLLocation object in ViewDidLoad and get location coordinatites in it delegate method

**Declate variable for current location**

```
var currentLocation : CLLocation
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
 var locManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            // ask permission - NOT NECESSARY IF YOU ALREADY ADDED NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription IT UP INFO.PLIST
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            // when in use foreground
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

**CLLocation's Delegate**

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // Get first location item returned from locations array
        currentLocation = locations[0]
        self.getAddressFromLatLon() // you can call here or whenever you want
    }
```

**Your method as below**

```
func getAddressFromLatLon() {

    var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let lat: Double = Double(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    //21.228124
    let lon: Double = Double(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    //72.833770
    let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    center.latitude = lat
    center.longitude = lon

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    var placemark: AnyObject
    var error: NSError
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locManager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if (placemark?.count)! > 0 {
            let pm = (placemark?[0])! as CLPlacemark
            //self.addressString = pm.locality! + pm.country!
            let adress = pm.locality! + " " + pm.country!

            print(adress)
        } else {
            print("Error with data")
        }
    })



}
```